# corresponding textbox for each user reference item

Tags: users

I have a special node type [I call it **members**] that includes a user reference field. The amount of user references that can be added to each members is unlimited.

But I need to add an extra information for each user that is added to each members node.

I am searching for a solution to put a text box input beside the node reference auto complete input.
I mean each auto complete user reference field has a corresponding text box input.

Even when the manager click on **add another** button and new auto complete line is appeared at the end of rows, the new corresponding text box input must be located beside it.

Please help me

How can I do this.

Comment: Nobody has an idea?!?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [field collections](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection).
In your members content type, create a field (say members collection) with multiple values. Then proceed to the field collections admin and add:

1. the user reference field
2. the textbox field

These two fields while creating the content type will now be 'one' with an 'add more' button under each.